# Does a injective function need every element of the domain to map onto some element of the codomain?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My question is, is it necessary for every element of the domain to map onto some element of the range for a function to be injective? For example, is

$$f(x) = x,\ f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb Z$$

one-to-one/injective, even though there are many elements of the reals that cannot map onto the integers? Obviously for every element that *can* map onto $\Bbb Z$, it is the only element that corresponds to its output, but I guess I'm wondering if this "overflow" of elements in $\Bbb R$ that don't map onto $\Bbb Z$ matter.

Another example, which is the reason I wanted to know the answer to this question:

$$f(x)= 1/x,\ f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$$

So obviously, every element of the domain points to only $1$ element of the range in this function, but does it matter that when $x=0$ the function is undefined? Or does that not effect whether the function is one-to-one or not?

Comment: For an injective function, each element of the codomain must have *at most 1* preimage in the domain.

Comment: The condition you ask about is part of the definition of being a *function* in the first place.

Comment: There does not seem to be a consensus in the answers below. By definition does a function map each element in the domain to the co-domain, or can a function partially map the elements in the domain? Maybe it depends on the context.
The title should be changed to "Does a *function* need every element of the domain to map onto some element of the codomain?", since this question applies to all functions, not just injective functions.

Answer (score 14):

$f(x) = x$ where $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb Z$ is not a function.

A function $f : A \to B$ is a set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that for every $a \in A$ there is exactly one $b \in B$ that pairs with that $a$, that is $f(a)$ exists and $f(a) = b$. In set builder form,

$$f = \{(a,b) : a \in A,\ f(a) = b \in B\}$$

Injectivity requires the reverse, that each $b$ only pairs with one $a$.

Now, for your proposed $f$, you have a bunch of $a \in \Bbb R$ that don't get mapped anywhere. What would that look like as an ordered pair? $(a,)$? This doesn't make sense. Every element of your domain must get mapped somewhere or else it isn't a function.

Comment: The answer above you disagrees. See partial function .

Comment: @john The OP asked about functions, not partial functions. It's fine to mention partial functions, but functions are a struct subset of partial function and not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with being one-to-one but is rather the definition of a *function* from a domain to a codomain (but of course, to be a one-to-one function, you first have to be a function at all).  If $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, that means that for each $a\in A$, $f(a)$ is defined and is an element of $B$.  So $f(x)=x$ is *not* a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, since $f(x)\not\in\mathbb{Z}$ for some values of $x$.  And $f(x)=1/x$ is not a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, since $f(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary every element of the domain to map onto some element in the codomain. A function that does not map all elements of its domain is called [partial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

The function from you first example ($f(x)=x, f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$) is *partial* and *bijective*. It is partial because there are arguments for which it is undefined ($f(1.5)$ is undefined). It is [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) because for every element $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is at least one element $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$ as $\mathbb{Z}\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$. It is [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) because every distinct element in $\mathbb{R}$ is mapped to a distinct element in $\mathbb{Z}$. It is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) because it is both injective and surjective.

Similarly, the function from your second example ($f(x)=1/x, f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$) is *partial* ($f(0)$ is undefined) and *bijective*.

In addition, function $f(x)=1/x, f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function) and *bijective*, while function $f(x)=1/x, f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is *partial* ($f(0)$ is undefined) and *non-surjective* (there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=0$).

Comment: I'd advise being more careful about how you phrase this. A "function" that does not map all elements of its domain *is not a function* but a more general object called a "partial function". In other words, a partial function is not a special type of function but, rather, the opposite is true; a function is a special type of partial function, sometimes called a "total function" in that context.